# Rejection Sampling Kurtosis and Number of Iterations

Tags: python, kurtosis, accept-reject

I tried to implement a rejection sampling method in python based on something explained during class. The target distribution is the normal distribution and the proposal is the exponential distribution. To accommodate for the different domains. The following pdf was used: 

\begin{align}X &\sim N(0,1)\\Z &= |X|\\ f_Z(x) &= \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} \; for \;x \geq 0\end{align}

The proposal function is:
$g_Y(y) = \frac{1}{2}e^\frac{-x}{2} \; for \; x \geq0$
with CDF: $G_Y(y) = 1 - e^\frac{-x}{2}.$

I first generated uniform random variables, $U \sim (0,1)$, using the `numpy.random.uniform` function, and then used the inverse CDF method to generate the exponential variables. Then, I simulated another uniform random variable to ascertain if the generated exponential should be accepted or rejected.

The method to accept was:
Accept if $U \leq\frac{f_Z(y)}{Mg_Y(y)},$ where $M = \max_y \frac{f_Y(y)}{g_Y(y)},~~\frac{f_Y(y)}{g_Y(y)} = \frac{4}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^\frac{x-x^2}{2} .$

Setting the derivative of this expression to 0, we can ascertain that the maximum is attained at $x = 0.5.$ 
This gives $M = \frac{4}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^\frac{1}{8} \approx 1.8082$
After a $1000$ variables are generated in this manner, I generated another uniform random variable to 'normalise' them.

$$\textrm{Set}~~ X=\begin{cases}Y ~&\textrm{if}\; U \leq 0.5\\-Y,~&\textrm{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

This is the code I have written:

```
def inv_exp(u):
    
    x = -2*np.log(1-u)
    return x

def g(x):
    y = 1/2*math.e**(-x/2)
    return y

def f(x):
    c = 2/(math.sqrt(2*math.pi))
    y = c*math.e**(-x**2/2)
    return y
      
def rej(n, M):
    X = np.zeros(n)
    count = 0
    for i in range(n):
        u = rnd.random()
        z = inv_exp(u)
        u2 = rnd.random()
        count += 1
        while u2 > f(z)/(M*g(z)):
            u = rnd.random()
            z = inv_exp(u)
            count += 1
        X[i] = z
    return X, count
```

As I understand, to generate $n$ variables, you would need $nM$ tries and therefore iterations in a program. According to the $M$ I have it should be $\approx 1800$ iterations to generate the sample. But the program consistently takes $\approx 2100$ iterations to generate a thousand variables. And the kurtosis values seem too high as well. These are the kurtosis values I got, running the program ten times.

```
[0.1528, 0.1860, -0.0430, 0.3701, 0.0406, -0.0956, 0.01683,0.2411,0.1685,-0.0073 ]
```

Is it normal to have such large deviations in kurtosis? And I do not understand why it takes over 2000 iterations to generate the values. Is there a mistake in my implementation or derivation of $M$?
Thanks

Comment: With the density for $Z$ you should indicate the interval where it takes the value in the formula you give (it's zero elsewhere, it doesn't take that value for all $z$)

Comment: Your kurtosis values seem consistent with sample kurtosis values from a normal at n=1000.

Comment: What probability are you seeking for getting at least 1000 values from N generated exponentials?

Comment: Sorry about that, I have edited it to include the support for the distribution. And I was worried about the kurtosis since in a previous exercise using the inverse CDF method, I was told by my prof that the kurtosis was too high. As for the last question you asked. As I understood $\frac{1}{M} \approx  0.553$ is the unconditional acceptance rate of a generated variable using this method. Then it follows that the number of variables you would have to generate to get $n$ of them accepted would be $\frac{n}{\frac{1}{M}}$. But that is not what I am getting at all.

Comment: 1. On the kurtosis, see the formula on the wikipedia page on kurtosis for the variance of g2; if you're using some other standard estimator you should still have the same variance asymptotically (the exact + or - on the n terms don't make much difference at n=1000). From that you can compute the standard error of the sample kurtosis -- then simulate kurtosis of 1000 values many times and use the sample sd of kurtosis for comparison.

Comment: 2. The number of values you need to generate is a random variable, specifically each generated normal requires a geometric-distributed number of exponentials. To generate N normals requires a negative binomial number of exponentials (a sum of iid geometrics). There's no upper limit on how many it takes. Hence my question about what probability you were seeking. ... or are you only concerned about the average of that negative binomial?

Comment: Thanks. Ill read up on the kurtosis. Should be an interesting exercise. I understand that there is no strict upper limit to how many variables need to be generated. What I meant was the average number of trials required to generate 'n' variables. The conditional probability of accepting a generated exponential variable  $y_0$ would be $\frac{f_Z(y_0)}{Mg_Y(y_0)}$ and the unconditional acceptance rate would be $P(U \leq\frac{f_Z(Y)}{Mg_Y(Y)}) = \frac{1}{M}$.Therefore, the probability I would like to have on average is $P = \frac{1}{M} \approx 0.553$, but I seem to be getting $P \approx 0.475$.

Comment: The number of rejections before a variable is accepted, as you have mentioned, is geometrically distributed. But the probability of acceptance is conditional on the generated exponential. Would it then still be negative binomial? Sorry if it sounds like I'm repeating myself in the comments.

Comment: Ok I feel dumb. I looked at the code again, and I fixed it. I am now getting $\approx 1800$iterations like I wanted. I had a really simple mistake in the code. I was not generating a new Uniform variable every time the generated exponential was rejected, but instead reusing the same one.  Thanks a lot for the advice.